# Angular http rxjs/Rx Observable Subscribe data binding not working

Tags: rxjs, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am trying to bind the data from PHP API to the client (Angular 2), however, it didn't work as expected. Any idea?

This is the laravel API code below,

```
 return response()-> json('message',200);
```

This is the Angular 2 service and subscribe as below,

```
  getString(): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.get(this.api_misc_url)
        .map((response: Response) => <string>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

This is the subscriber code as below,

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartId = `mydash-chart-${MydashChartComponent.currentId++}`;

   this.laravelApiService.getString().subscribe(
            messageFromLaravelApi => this.MessageFromLaravelApi = <string>messageFromLaravelApi,
            error => this.errorMessage = <string>error);
  }
```

This is the UI binding code below,

```
   <div class='panel-heading' >
    <h2>Charting </h2>


                    <td>{{ MessageFromLaravelApi }}</td>


</div>
```

But, I can see value shown on the console log.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either use `subscribe` or `async` , not both. `async` takes an observable or promise and renders data .

**Either this**

```
   this.MessageFromLaravelApi$ = this.laravelApiService.getString();
```

http :

```
<tr *ngFor="let message of MessageFromLaravelApi$ | async">
    <td>{{ message }}</td>
</tr>
```

**OR**

```
this.laravelApiService.getString()
   .subscribe(
       messageFromLaravelApi => 
            this.MessageFromLaravelApi = messageFromLaravelApi,
       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```

http

```
<tr *ngFor="let message of MessageFromLaravelApi">
    <td>{{ message }}</td>
</tr>
```

---

**Updating the same code :**

Service code

```
  getString(): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.get(this.api_misc_url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(err=> console.error(err));
  }
```

Component Code :

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chartId = `mydash-chart-${MydashChartComponent.currentId++}`;

   this.laravelApiService.getString().subscribe(
            messageFromLaravelApi => 
      this.MessageFromLaravelApi = messageFromLaravelApi,
            error => this.errorMessage = error);
  }
```

HTML

```
   <div class='panel-heading' >
    <h2>Charting </h2>


                    <td>{{ MessageFromLaravelApi }}</td>


</div>
```

Comment: I tried the second option but still no luck. Also, I updated the API code above. I have removed the async but only the subscribe. @Skeptor

Comment: You are getting response as `{ message: 'Testing', message2: 'Testing 2 '}` which is not an array. In HTML remove others and  try just `{{ MessageFromLarabelApi}}`

Comment: I tried this few times earlier it didn't work, and I just tried again, no luck :(! @Skeptor.

Comment: `console.log` in subscribe and see what data you are getting. Remove `String[]` in service as the data is not array of strings

Comment: Please see my updated codes, still no luck. Just wondering that do I have to put the ngIf checking in this case? @Skeptor

Comment: the return type of your service function is still wrong, the function returns an observable of an object with the from {message:string, message2:string}, not an string

Comment: I have updated my codes again, this time I think I am pretty right but still I can't bind the 'messge' from the service. Really weird! @Jota. Toleda

Comment: You still have `<string>` . you must understand the HTTP response you are getting is an object, not string. I updated my answer with code you can use. Specifically mention the error if you get an error.

Comment: Well! I know the difference between String and Object, the API just only return as a string and the angular two service just simply get and map the Observable<string>, then the component subscribes it and assigns to the variable declared as a string again. The binding just doesn't work! I even created a dummy method in my angular two services just only return an object, which looks like this {"id":"1"}, and it works.I am a little puzzled now because subscribing a string from any API is nothing complicated; maybe I am still having error somewhere in my code.@Skeptor

Comment: May I have your Skype ID? Or any communication tool you prefer? Thank you. @Skeptor

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/146880/sketptors-angular-chat?tab=general You can join here